# NoMethodError in ProductsController#email_product , Emailer rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am trying to configure "Emailer" for the "Product class", but I have an error like : undefined method `send_product' for ProductMailer:Class. In this case , I defined that method. 
This is my Emailer class :

```
class ProductMailer < ActionMailer::Base
default from: "from@example.com"

# Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
# with the following lookup:
#
#   en.product_mailer.send_prodcut.subject
#
def send_prodcut
@greeting = "Hi"

mail to: "to@example.org"
end

# Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
# with the following lookup:
#
#   en.product_mailer.spam.subject

end
```

AND this is my productscontroller :

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_authen!
before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def email_product
ProductMailer.send_product().deliver
end
```

AND this is my route:

```
match '/login',   to: 'static_pages#login',   via: 'get'
match '/index' , to: 'stores#index', via: 'get'
match '/show/:id', to: 'stores#show', via: 'get', :as=> 'show'
get  "emailproduct" => "products#email_product", :as => "email_product"
```

Any advise? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo on your method definition in `ProductMailer`

Should be

```
def send_product
 @greeting = "Hi"

 mail to: "to@example.org"
end
```

Instead of

```
def send_prodcut
 @greeting = "Hi"

 mail to: "to@example.org"
end
```